# ASUS 797-AR BSOD when two DIMM channels are in use

Tags: memory, motherboard, bsod

I've run into a very strange issue. Built a new machine this past weekend and everything was running smoothly for about four days. Then I had a stick of RAM die. Exchanged them for a new pair and now I've run into this new issue.

I have installed two, 4gb sticks, placed in the A2 and B2 slots as instructed by the manual. When both sticks are in place I receive a host of BSOD crashes when under load. Doing some troubleshooting, I've discovered that if I have one stick in A2 the system is rock solid. Tried just running in B2, also solid. Just in case, I tried each stick individually to make sure they both worked this way. As soon as I try both, the system crashes.

I've run Memtest86 and everything comes up roses.

Specs: 
Asus 797-AR motherboard 
Patriot Signature 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3  
Intel Core i7-4790 Processor 
GeForce 770 nVidia 
Corsair 850w PSU

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a timing issue between the sticks.  Basically the new sticks don't like each other, or one of them is faulty.  Try another new pair, or better, try a known-good pair.

Comment: Alternative ideas: a) Power requirements more than available as both are in place? b) Either of them pulls more than is normal and more than is available. c) Might also be a power source problem with a similar effect. Do you know what ESD is? If not, then look it up and read thoroughly.

Comment: This will be my third set, if that's the case. First set had a stick die, second was a pre-opened box from Fry's that I took a chance on (that pair would BSOD on the OS booting), and now this pair. If this is my problem, then I just had a bad run of RAM! heh